# PHP combine two seperate conflicting date ranges into unique pairs

Tags: php, date, date-range

Set one:

1. 2014-04-05 To 2014-06-27
2. 2014-06-28 To 2014-10-19

Set two:

1. 2014-04-05 To 2014-05-02
2. 2014-05-03 To 2014-05-31
3. 2014-06-01 To 2014-10-19

What I need this to output is:

1. 2014-04-05 To 2014-05-02
2. 2014-05-03 To 2014-05-31
3. 2014-06-01 To 2014-06-27
4. 2014-06-28 To 2014-10-19

I attempted to use a function to check for overlaps as such:

```
!($lhs['RecordOnset'] > $rhs['RecordOffset'] || $lhs['RecordOffset'] < $rhs['RecordOnset'])
```

And used a for loop to check for the overlap:

```
for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($arr1); $i++) {
    for($j = 1; $j < sizeof($arr2); $j++) {
        $record = $arr1[$i];
        if($result = $this->intersects($arr1[$i], $arr2[$j])) {
            // $result;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm having is when I break a date range out, it doesn't check the new range that was created when looping. I do not have the ability to use SQL with this so I must come up with a programmatic solution. I've tried several different methods including some foreach loops.

The data is received in a date format as show in an array like such:

```
$arr1 = array(array('start'=>'04/05/2014', 'end'=> '2014-06-27'), array('start'=>'2014-06-28', 'end'=> '2014-10-19'));

$arr2 = array(array('start'=>'04/05/2014', 'end'=> '2014-05-02'), array('start'=>'2014-05-03', 'end'=> '2014-05-31'),array('start'=>'2014-06-01', 'end'=> '2014-10-19'));
```

The second pair would be a separate array, since it may have the same keys.

Any guidance or help with this is greatly appreciated. Date ranges with PHP has very limited resource online.

Comment: Well is this range a string, 2 seperate date/timestamps, how do you receive this data,..?? Add the data from the arrays or w/e to your question.

Comment: What I use is a date format in an array.. so for example the first set is: array(array('start'=>'04/05/2014', 'end'=> '2014-06-27'), array('start'=>'2014-06-28', 'end'=> '2014-10-19'))

Comment: You are looking to find all the time periods that are available in both arrays, right? Like for trying to find when two people can meet given that you only know when their vacations start and end?

Comment: That is a great example of what I am trying to do. Using ranges, keep time frames unique.. exactly like a calendar, finding the times when two people have appointments and the times they are free outside of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage : `$output = mergeRanges($input);`

This method is originally designed to merge any kind on numeric ranges, timestamps included and supports any kind of overlaps. It takes an array of objects in input, containing "from" and "to" keys which is customizable.

```php
/**
 * @param        $ranges
 * @param string $keyFrom
 * @param string $keyTo
 *
 * @return array
 */
function mergeRanges($ranges, $keyFrom = 'from', $keyTo = 'to')
{
    // Split from / to values.
    $arrayFrom = [];
    $arrayTo   = [];
    foreach ($ranges as $date)
    {
        $arrayFrom[] = $date->$keyFrom;
        $arrayTo[]   = $date->$keyTo;
    }

    // Sort ASC.
    natsort($arrayFrom);
    natsort($arrayTo);

    $ranges = [];
    // Iterate over start dates.
    foreach ($arrayFrom as $indexFrom => $from)
    {
        // Get previous entry.
        $previousEntry = end($ranges);
        // Find associated default "to" value to "from" one.
        $to = $arrayTo[$indexFrom];

        // If we have a previous entry and "to" is greater than
        // current "from" value.
        if (isset($previousEntry->to) && $from < $previousEntry->to + 1)
        {
            // Do nothing if this range is completely covered
            // by the previous one.
            if ($to > $previousEntry->to)
            {
                // We just change te "to" value of previous range,
                // so we don't create a new entry.
                $previousEntry->to = $to;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new range entry.
            $ranges[] = (object) [
                $keyFrom => $from,
                $keyTo   => $to,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $ranges;
}
```

Example :

```
$input = [
    // One day.
    (object) [
        'title' => 'One day.',
        'from'  => 1560816000,
        'to'    => 1560902399,
    ],
    // Same day, inner period
    (object) [
        'title' => 'Same day, inner period',
        'from'  => 1560816000 + 1000,
        'to'    => 1560902399 - 1000,
    ],
    // Just before midnight
    (object) [
        'title' => 'Just before midnight',
        'from'  => 1560816000 - 1000,
        'to'    => 1560816000 + 1000,
    ],
    // Just after midnight
    (object) [
        'title' => 'Just after midnight',
        'from'  => 1560902399 - 1000,
        'to'    => 1560902399 + 1000,
    ],
    // Other period before
    (object) [
        'title' => 'Other period before',
        'from'  => 1560902399 - 100000,
        'to'    => 1560902399 - 100000 + 5000,
    ],
    // Other period after
    (object) [
        'title' => 'Other period after',
        'from'  => 1560816000 + 100000,
        'to'    => 1560902399 + 100000 + 5000,
    ],
];
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2019-06-17 22:13:19
            [to] => 2019-06-17 23:36:39
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2019-06-18 01:43:20
            [to] => 2019-06-19 02:16:39
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2019-06-19 05:46:40
            [to] => 2019-06-20 07:09:59
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    array('s'=>'2014-04-05','e'=>'2014-06-27'),
    array('s'=>'2014-06-28','e'=>'2014-10-19')
);
$array2 = array(
    array('s'=>'2014-04-05','e'=>'2014-05-02'),
    array('s'=>'2014-05-03','e'=>'2014-05-31'),
    array('s'=>'2014-06-01','e'=>'2014-10-19')
);

//merge arrays together
$merged_array = array_merge($array1,$array2);

//filter out duplicate start dates
$filtered_array = array();
foreach($merged_array as $k=>$v){
    if(!isset($filtered_array[ $v['s'] ] )){
        $filtered_array[ $v['s'] ] = $v;
    }

    //if the end date is before the currently saved end date (for this start date) then use it
    if( strtotime($v['e']) < strtotime($filtered_array[ $v['s'] ]['e']) ){
        $filtered_array[ $v['s'] ] = $v;
    }
}

//reset the array to zero based
$filtered_array = array_values($filtered_array);

//sort the array by start date
$tmp = array();
foreach($filtered_array as $k=>$v){
    $tmp[$k] = $v['s'];
}

array_multisort($tmp,SORT_ASC,$filtered_array);

//end date overlap checking
foreach($filtered_array as $k=>$v){
    //if the end date is after (or equal to) the "next" start date, then make that end date the "yesterday" of the next start date
    if( isset($filtered_array[$k+1]['s']) && strtotime($v['e']) >= strtotime($filtered_array[$k+1]['s'])  ){
        $yesterday = strtotime($filtered_array[$k+1]['s']) - 1;
        $yesterday = date("Y-m-d",$yesterday);
        $filtered_array[$k]['e'] = $yesterday;
    }
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($filtered_array),'</pre>';

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [s] => 2014-04-05
            [e] => 2014-05-02
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [s] => 2014-05-03
            [e] => 2014-05-31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [s] => 2014-06-01
            [e] => 2014-06-27
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [s] => 2014-06-28
            [e] => 2014-10-19
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. This looks good so far and I am attempting to test this. So far, when I return the result (which has more data in the original array that start and end), the dates are not in order from least to greatest.

Comment: my solution may not be perfect, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction. `array_multisort()` should allow you to resort your array based on the start date

Answer (score 1):

*Preparing*

```
$arr1 = array(
  array('start'=>'2014-04-05', 'end'=> '2014-06-27'),
  array('start'=>'2014-06-28', 'end'=> '2014-10-19'),
);

$arr2 = array(
  array('start'=>'2014-04-05', 'end'=> '2014-05-02'),
  array('start'=>'2014-05-03', 'end'=> '2014-05-31'),
  array('start'=>'2014-06-01', 'end'=> '2014-10-21')
);

// merge arrays
$all = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);

// divide start-dates and end-dates into two arrays
$starts = array();
$ends = array();
foreach($all as $date){
    $starts[] = $date['start'];
    $ends[] = $date['end'];
}

// Remove duplicates and "sort ASC"
$starts = array_unique($starts);
natsort($starts);

$ends = array_unique($ends);
natsort($ends);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($starts,$ends);
echo '</pre>';
```

*output*

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-05"
    [3]=>
  string(10) "2014-05-03"
    [4]=>
  string(10) "2014-06-01"
    [1]=>
  string(10) "2014-06-28"
}
array(5) {
    [2]=>
  string(10) "2014-05-02"
    [3]=>
  string(10) "2014-05-31"
    [0]=>
  string(10) "2014-06-27"
    [1]=>
  string(10) "2014-10-19"
    [4]=>
  string(10) "2014-10-21"
}
```

Ok. Now we need loop array `$starts`: for each `start` find closest `end` that more then `start`. Do it:

```
$ranges = array();

foreach($starts as $start){
    $start_time = strtotime($start);

    foreach($ends as $end){
        $end_time = strtotime($end);
        if ($start_time>$end_time) continue;
        else{
            $ranges[$end] = $start;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// "combine" 
$result = array();    
foreach($ranges as $end=>$start) {
    $result[] = array('start' => $start, 'end' => $end);
}

// print final result
foreach($result as $item){
    echo $item['start'].'  To  '.$item['end'].'<br/>';
}
```

*output*:

```
2014-04-05 To 2014-05-02
2014-05-03 To 2014-05-31
2014-06-01 To 2014-06-27
2014-06-28 To 2014-10-19
```

What you need.

**Note** 
About this line in loops:

```
 $ranges[$end] = $start;
```

We can have this situation:

```
2014-04-03 To 2014-05-02
2014-04-04 To 2014-05-02
2014-04-05 To 2014-05-02
```

But it's wrong. Need only last range `2014-04-05 To 2014-05-02`. And line:

```
 $ranges[$end] = $start;
```

override value with same key=> finally will be set proper `2014-04-05` to key `2014-05-02`.

Comment: I am going to work on implementing this solution as it is digestible and easy to understand what is going on. Can you explain to me what the last part was meaning -- $ranges[$end] = $start. I don't think I'm following your explanation on that.

Comment: @Nick McCally you can change `$ranges[$end] = $start;` to line `$ranges[] = array( 'start'=>$start, 'end' =>  $end)`;. If you did it => need remove also `"combine"` loop. Then you can see why I made like `$ranges[$end] = $start;`

Comment: Nope, I fully see what you mean now. Thank you so very much for the detailed explanation on the full soliton.  Such a simple way of handling this too.. Sometimes we all have brain farts